# How to get geolocation every 5 minutes even app is not running state in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing an enterprise application using Cordova(Phonegap). 
I have to get location updates every 5 minutes and send it to my web services, even if the application is in background(not in the running state).

Does anybody have a solution or an idea for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is plugin in Cordova for getting geolocation in background

[cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

hope it will help with what you're looking for.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service and keep it running if it the app is not in the running state, so to say, meaning in background. For this you can implement a foreground service like here:
[Implementing a foreground service](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/simple-android-foreground-service-example/)

Then while the service is on, you start collecting location updates and send it to your web service.
I hope I got you right and that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrei, But i am looking in cordova. How to do in cordova(Phonegap) app.

Comment: Well, I did this once, and as far as I can recall, the interaction from android app and web interface was done via a plugin. The plugin was accessing some interface that was interacting with the service and was sending updates to the plugin. This was back in 2013, things might have changed since then.

Comment: Hi, If you know any plugins please help me..i want to support for iOS and Android platforms

Comment: First learn how to write plugins then try to make a demo app using the observer pattern, such that you get the notification in the plugin and afterwards you can update your web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enable the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the `location` value in your Info.plist file of your app (see full details in this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).